# How to stack elements without using z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
<nav>
        <div class="slider" id="slider"></div>
        <div class="titleGroup">
            <h2 onclick="selectArticles()" id="articlesButton" class="active">Articles</h2>
            <h2 onclick="selectSocial()" id="socialButton">Social</h2>
        </div>
        
    </nav>
```

I need to make the slider appear on top of titleGroup but under its h2 childs, is there a way to do it using javascript? Making the h2s appear on top of everything would work too.

I tried doing it with z-index but obviously it doesn't work because z-index is relative to the parent.

Comment: all children `.titleGroup` is h2?

Comment: @TachibanaShin yes

Comment: actually i don't understand the requirement you want `.slider` above `.titleGroup` but below `.titleGroup > h2` although it can be done but since only h2 it will show same as `,slider` below `.titleGroup`. in `.titleGroup` do you have `background` or `:before` or `:after`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TachibanaShin yeah in `.titleGroup` i have a background, that's the reason why I need it to be in the middle between `.titleGroup` and `.titleGroup > h2`

Comment: i can do it easily without javscript or change the html but i need to use `z-index` (this is a css hack) please correct the question

Comment: It's actually possible to solve your problem using `z-index`. Note that z-index is not always relative to parent if the parent has the default value for the `position` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually possible to solve your current problem using z-index and no JavaScript
(assuming you're not doing something funny with your `titleGroup`).

```css
nav{
  position:relative;
}
.titleGroup {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#slider{
  z-index:1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  height: 80px;
  left: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#slider::before{
  content: "Slider in front of titleGroup background, but behind h2"
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  background: cyan;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="slider" id="slider"></div>
  <div class="titleGroup" id="titleGroup">
    <h2 onclick="selectArticles()" id="articlesButton" class="active">Articles</h2>
    <h2 onclick="selectSocial()" id="socialButton">Social</h2>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Note that `.titleGroup` has no special value for `position` (or `z-index` for that matter), so no new stacking context is created.

(And if a css statement somehow affects your titleGroup element’s `position` property, you can use `position:unset` or `position:static`)

More about stacking context: [Link1 (The stacking context
)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

The following has an example where elements that are not siblings can be controlled just using z-index: [Link2 (Stacking context example 1
)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_context_example_1)

In my example, `h2` and `#slider` are not siblings, but since `.titleGroup` has no stacking context, in effect the behavior of `z-index`es is comparable that of siblings.

Also note that this fails if your `.titleGroup` has `opacity` value less than 1, as it creates a new stacking context, and similarly if you have a special filter, etc. (described in the first link).

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for JavaScript solution... you can `prepend` it to be the first child of the `.titleGroup`. But of course a better approach would have been to fix the HTML or try with `z-index`.

```js
titleGroup.prepend(slider)
```

```css
.titleGroup {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
}

h2 {
position:relative;
background: black;
}

.slider {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="slider" id="slider">I am slider</div>
  <div class="titleGroup" id="titleGroup">
    <h2 onclick="selectArticles()" id="articlesButton" class="active">Articles</h2>
    <h2 onclick="selectSocial()" id="socialButton">Social</h2>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Don't use javascript for such silly reasons